# Geometric sequence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

How do I use a geometric sequence with a investment of 5000 and a 5 percent increase each year of the new value? I've been trying everything and I just can't get the answer right. Please help

So year:
0 = 5000

1. 5250
2. 5512.5
3. 5788.13

Code so far:

```
def calc_profits(principal, year):
    INTREST_GROWTH = 0.05
    for profits in range (1, year):
        y = year
        p = principal

        profits = [p * (INTREST_GROWTH ** (y - 1)) for y in range(1, y + 1)]
        print("{} {:.2f}".format(profits(year, principal)))
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: def calc_profits(principal, year):
   
    INTREST_GROWTH = 0.05
    for profits in range (1, year):
        y = year
        p = principal
        
        
        profits = float[p * (INTREST_GROWTH ** (y - 1)) for y in range(1, INTREST_GROWTH + 1)]
        print("{}        {:.2f}".format(profits(year, principal)))

Comment: please update code in your question.

Comment: Could you add that to the question? That way people will be able to see how you've formatted the code as well.

Comment: Okay I just. edited it. The principal value is not really 5000, I wan't it to be a variable.

Comment: normally you want to directly copy your code on here instead of posting pictures

Comment: for y in range(1, INTREST_GROWTH + 1) the range in this is most likely supposed to be range(1, y+1)

Comment: Okay, I'll make note of that, thank you

Comment: The problem is, I tried that. When I validate my code, no problems show up. However, when I run the code, there is no output even though I have inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your print statement.

you have 2 options to get it working:

1. list comprehension, creats the full list of profits and then zips them with years

   `def calc_profits(principal, year):
       INTREST_GROWTH = 0.05
       profits = [principal * ((1+INTREST_GROWTH) ** (y - 1)) for y in range(1, year + 1)]
       for i,p in zip(range(year),profits):
           print("{0}:{1:.2f}".format(i, p))`
2. Iteration gives a new value and prints it for every loop iteration

   `def calc_profits(principal, year):
       INTREST_GROWTH = 0.05
       profits = principal
       for y in range(1, year):
           profits = profits*(INTREST_GROWTH+1)
           print("{0}:{1:.2f}".format(y, profits))`

Answer (score -1):

You can just calculate the end value of your investment and take away the principal to find out how much profit you made.

```
def calc_profits(principal, year):
    INTEREST_GROWTH = 0.05
    end_capital = principal * (1 + INTEREST_GROWTH) ** year
    profit = end_capital - principal
    return profit
```

EDIT: If you want to know the profits at each year, you can do it with list comprehensions.

```
def calc_profits(principal, year):
    INTEREST_GROWTH = 0.05
    profit = [principal * (1 + INTEREST_GROWTH) ** y - principal
               for y in range(1, year + 1)]
    return profit
```

Comment: This works thanks. Shouldn't I have a range if I want to make a list? Like If I enter 5 as my year variable, I still want the values of 1 to 4 to show up like a table of values. How do I do that?

Comment: @Sarah I have updated the answer to show the profits for every year as a list.